# How to mport RGL plot in a tcl tk window with R

Tags: r, 3d, tcl, tk-toolkit, rgl

I want to display an interactive 3D plot in a TCL TK window. I wonder if it is possible.

Here is a code poping up a new window (device) doing that.

```
library(rgl)
attach(mtcars)
plot3d(wt, disp, mpg, col="red", size=5)
```

The problem is I can't add button to that window.

I want to put the interactive area of the window above in a TCL TK I created like this :

```
tt <- tktoplevel()
```

Anyone knows how to do that ?

Comment: Ugh; there ought to be a way to embed that 3D surface, but can I pick my way through the rgl documentation to find it? No.

Answer (score 1):

This is cobbled together from the example in `?tkrgl::spinControl`. I'm not sure it does exactly what you described but it does illustrate how to control an rgl-device with a tk control window:

```
install.packages("tkrgl")  # also by Duncan Murdoch
library("tkrgl")
plot3d(wt, disp, mpg, col="red", size=5)
win1 <- rgl.cur()
rgl.bringtotop(TRUE)
#Warning message:
#In rgl.bringtotop(TRUE) : stay not implemented
 base <- tktoplevel()
 tkwm.title(base, "Spinners")
# <Tcl>  
 con1 <- spinControl(base, dev=c(win1))
 tkpack(con1)
#<Tcl>  
 base <- tktoplevel()
 tkwm.title(base, "Spinners")
 con1 <- spinControl(base, dev=c(win1))
 tkpack(con1)
```

[image]